# Error Authentication Firebase se sale Solo del usuario

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo una App con Android Studio y uso firebase para el login, antes de entrar al usuario primero se registra dejando unos datos basicos(email, correo, telefono entre otros) y envia también dos imagenes la de perfil y otra que se use de fondo, para enviar estos datos a firebase primero lo autentifico con los datos que ya dejo y luego entra directamente a la sesion del usuario, uso el metodo onAuthStateChanged para saber en que mometno se encuentra logueado pero cuando uso mi botón de registro para enviar los datos en el metodo onAuthStateChanged me muestra que se ha salido hasta 3 veces de la sesión y debido a esto no puede guardar la información en firebase ya que necesita estar autenticado, este es el codigo que uso para autenticar a los usuarios:

```
public void authenticationUsers(final Activity activity, FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth,
                                final String email, String pw){

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw).addOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.i(Constants.TAG_USER_AUTH, "Authentication Success");
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, NoticesActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication Unsuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Este es el metodo que uso para enviar los datos a firebase:

```
public void uploadDatesForRegisterusers(StorageReference storageReference, String dateCreate,
                                        String names, String lastnames, Bitmap imageUserPerfil,
                                       Activity activity, final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth,
                                       String email, String pw,
                                       final DatabaseReference databaseReference,
                                       final String nickname,
                                       Bitmap imageUser){

    authenticationRegister(activity, firebaseAuth, email, pw);

    DatesSet datesSet = new DatesSet(databaseReference.push().getKey(), dateCreate,
            nickname, names, lastnames, email, pw);
    databaseReference.child(Constants.DATES_NODE)
            .child(nickname)
            .child(Constants.DATES_NODE_CHILD)
            .setValue(datesSet);

    final StorageReference imageReference = storageReference
            .child(names+"_"+lastnames)
            .child(names+"_"+lastnames+"_perfil.png");
    UploadTask uploadTask = imageReference.putBytes(convertImageBytes(imageUserPerfil));
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(Constants.TAG_USER_AUTH, "Ocurrió un error en la subida");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            imageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Uri uriPhoto = uri;
                    String photourl = uriPhoto.toString();
                    String urlPhotoUserPerfil = photourl;
                    Log.w("Urls", urlPhotoUserPerfil);
                    UrlUser setUrl = new UrlUser(urlPhotoUserPerfil);
                    databaseReference.child(Constants.DATES_NODE)
                            .child(nickname)
                            .child("Urls")
                            .child("UrlPerfil")
                            .setValue(setUrl);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    final StorageReference imageReferenceUser = storageReference
            .child(names+"_"+lastnames)
            .child(names+"_"+lastnames+"_image.png");
    UploadTask uploadTaskImage = imageReferenceUser.putBytes(convertImageBytes(imageUser));
    uploadTaskBike.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(Constants.TAG_USER_AUTH, "Ocurrió un error en la subida");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Log.w("UrlSimple", imageReferenceUser.getDownloadUrl().toString());
            imageReferenceUser.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Uri uriPhoto = uri;
                    String photourl = uriPhoto.toString();
                    String urlPhotoUser = photourl;
                    Log.w("Urls", urlPhotoUser);
                    UrlUser setUrlUser = new UrlUser(urlPhotoUser);
                    databaseReference.child(Constants.DATES_NODE)
                            .child(nickname)
                            .child("Urls")
                            .child("UrlUser")
                            .setValue(setUrlUser);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Estos metodos se encuentran en una clase aparte desde donde accedo a ellos y paso los parametros, llamo estos metodos cuando se encuentra en el evento onClick del boton registrar pero no veo en ningun momento que se salga del usuario autenticado antes de terminar de hacer lo otros metodos, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: que es lo que hace authenticationRegister ? y donde llamas al metodo uploadDatesForRegisterusers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en que las llamadas a Firebase son asyncronas, eso quiere decir que no vas a saber con exactitud cuando terminan.

Cuando haces esto

```
 public void uploadDatesForRegisterusers(StorageReference storageReference, String dateCreate,
                                            String names, String lastnames, Bitmap imageUserPerfil,
                                           Activity activity, final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth,
                                           String email, String pw,
                                           final DatabaseReference databaseReference,
                                           final String nickname,
                                           Bitmap imageUser){

        authenticationRegister(activity, firebaseAuth, email, pw);
...
```

El metodo `authenticationRegister` invoca una llamada asincrona, mientras esta llamada esta terminando de ejecutarse (que todavia no lo hizo) , enseguida estas llamando a la insersion de datos al usuario

```
DatesSet datesSet = new DatesSet(databaseReference.push().getKey(), dateCreate,
            nickname, names, lastnames, email, pw);
    databaseReference.child(Constants.DATES_NODE)
            .child(nickname)
            .child(Constants.DATES_NODE_CHILD)
            .setValue(datesSet);
```

Por lo que `authenticationRegister` aun no ah terminado y estas seteando valores a firebase, cuando `authenticationRegister` termine, tu `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` va a cambiar, y es ahi donde tenes problemas.

La solucion es mover el codigo debajo de `authenticationRegister()`, adentro de la llamada `onComplete()` o `onSuccess()` de `authenticationRegister()`, con esto te aseguras que el flujo se mantenga.